# How to sort products in CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: php, sorting, web, codeigniter-3, backend

I am creating small e shop for selling products in it, but I cannot figure out How I need to sort. So I need to sort items in terms of brands, price range, gender (for man or woman). If user gives me all three details, I just do it in 3 where statement, like this:

```
$this->db->where('brands', $brand_name);
$this->db->where('price', $price);
$this->db->where('gender', $gen);
```

But what if user just gives me just 2 categories, will empty where statement make problem? and if user gives me multiple brand names, how can I write multiple where statements for sorting?

Thank you

Comment: Please put some effort into solving the question by yourself or try going through examples before asking for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Such construction will work regardless if `$brand_name` contains a string or an 
array

```
$this->db->where_in('brands', (array) $brand_name);
```